# Positive integers a and b such that $\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There exists positive integers a and b such that $\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{b}$

How am I suppose to find these?

I squared both sides, turned out nasty though.

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After squaring both sides you should get:

$$7-2\sqrt{a}=(5+b)-2\sqrt{5b}$$

Now if you observe both sides you can make a system of equations:

\begin{cases}
7=5+b\\
a=5b
\end{cases}
$\therefore b=2,$ $a=5b=10$